# How to find the list of all available packages along with the lastest version number available in the repositories?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I want to list all the packages(*installed or not installed*) along with the latest version number available in the repositories.

For example:

The output of `apt-cache policy chromium-browser` shows like below

```
$ apt-cache policy chromium-browser
chromium-browser:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

So the latest version of `chromium-browser` package available in the repository is `34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2`. Like that, i want to list the version number along with the package names that are available in repositories. And all i want to do this through command-line.

I want the output to be like this,

```
chromium-browser 34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyyyyy
............     ............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-cache policy '.*'` displays detailed version information for all packages.

If you want a more compact output with one line per package, you can use aptitude. The following command lists available versions (see the manual for [output format specifications](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s05s01.html)) for all packages except cross-architecture ones (e.g. 32-bit packages on a 64-bit system) (see the manual for [search patterns](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html)):

```
aptitude search -F '%54p %24V' '~rnative'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command will list all the available packages along with their latest version numbers available in repositories.

```
for i in $(apt-cache search all | awk -F' - ' '{print $1}'); do apt-cache policy $i | sed -n '1,3p' | sed ':a;N;s/\n//g;ba'; done | awk '{print $1,$5}'
```

**Example:**

```
$ for i in $(apt-cache search all | awk -F' - ' '{print $1}'); do apt-cache policy $i | sed -n '1,3p' | sed ':a;N;s/\n//g;ba'; done | awk '{print $1,$5}'
acpica-tools: 20140214-1ubuntu1
acpid: 1:2.0.21-1ubuntu2
activity-log-manager: 0.9.7-0ubuntu14
adduser: 3.113+nmu3ubuntu3
advancecomp: 1.18-1
aide: 0.16~a2.git20130520-2
aide-common: 0.16~a2.git20130520-2
alembic: 0.6.2+ds-1
alien: 8.90
alsa-base: 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4
amavisd-new: 1:2.7.1-2ubuntu3
anacron: 2.3-20ubuntu1
android-headers: 4.2.2-2-0ubuntu1
android-tools-fsutils: 4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu23
antlr: 2.7.7+dfsg-5
apache2: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apache2-bin: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apache2-dev: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apache2-mpm-event: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apache2-mpm-prefork: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apache2-mpm-worker: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apache2-utils: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apache2.2-bin: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
apg: 2.2.3.dfsg.1-2ubuntu1
^C
```

I take the first package and then do `apt-cache policy` on that, it displays the same version number as displayed by the above `for` command,

```
$ apt-cache policy acpica-tools
acpica-tools:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20140214-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     20140214-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache dump`

*N.B.:* This is a very large output. You will want to use a pager like `less`, or redirect this output to a file.

Comment: Additionally, you can find information on command-line options and syntax for almost every command, including `apt-get` and `apt-cache` by calling the `man` command, which would have answered this question for you, and may be of use to you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to accomplish what you're asking.

```
gawk '/^Package:/{printf $2 "\t"} /^Version:/{print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

It should be somewhat faster than parsing the output of another command too. If you want to mess with the formatting (for `package: version` — note that's not what your question asks for), you can change the first `printf` to:

```
printf $2 ": "
```